# Not able to consume configmap in one of my replicationcontroller in Kubernertes

Tags: configuration, kubernetes

I have created configmap using setenv.sh file with name `configmap-setenv`.I just want to consume this configmap in one of my replicationcontroller.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: sample-registrationweb-rc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: "JWS"
    role: "FO-registrationweb"
    tier: "app"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "JWS"
        role: "FO-registrationweb"
        tier: "app"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jws
        image: samplejws/demo:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: jws
            containerPort: 8080

        resources:
            requests:
               cpu: 1000m
               memory: 100Mi
            limits:
               cpu: 2000m
               memory: 7629Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/soft/jws-3.0/tomcat8/bin
          name: tomcatbin
      volumes:
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
      - configMap:
        name: tomcatbin
          name: configmap-setenv
          items:
          - key: setenv.sh
            path: setenv.sh
```

I am getting below error during creation fo replicationcontroller.

```
error validating "registartion-rc.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field configMap for v1.Volume; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. A newer version of `kubectl` would give you a more specific error: 
`yaml: line 40: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

The configmap volume mount should look like:

```
  volumes:
  - name: tomcatbin
    configMap:
      name: configmap-setenv
      items:
      - key: setenv.sh
        path: setenv.sh
```

Comment: Is the indentation correct for you? It works for me on 1.3/1.3 client/server.

Comment: I checked indentation that is proper

Comment: FYI,I am using below version of kubernetes. Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0"}